# apply arrayfun for a couple of values

Tags: matlab

I wrote a syntax that calculate values of a function in different values.
For example

```
x1=[1 2 10 11];
x2=[10 11 12 14];
C= arrayfun (@(t1,t2) myfunction(A,B,t1,t2),x1,x2,'UniformOutput',0);
% A and B are matrixs
```

In this example the function will do an operation on `A(x1,x2)` and `B(x1,x2)` . The problem is that arrayfun will work on each couple `(x1(1),x2(1)), x1(2),x2(2))`,etc. But I want it to work on all the values of x1 and x2 (16 couples of values so that it can be applied also to for example `(x1(1),x2(3))`).

Is there any way to do that without a loop?

Comment: i.e. you want all combinations of x1 and x2 ? look at `combvec` https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `ndgrid`:

```
 [X Y]  = ndgrid(x1,x2);
 C= arrayfun (@(x1,x2) myfunction(A,B,t1,t2),X(:),Y(:),'UniformOutput',0);
```

Comment: You can leave out `(:)` and get a 2D result, which may be more meaningful

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to offer the "dumb" way of doing it without you having to modify your call to your function:

```
x1=[1 2 10 11];
x2=[10 11 12 14];
v = combvec(x1,x2);
X1 = v(1,:);
X2 = v(2,:);

C= arrayfun (@(X1,X2) myfunction(A,B,t1,t2),X1,X2,'UniformOutput',0);
```

This effectively calculated all combinations of x1 and x2, then you input it thru your function in pairs just like you were doing it before.

Comment: Thank's for the  help !